# Circle text animation bugfixing

Tags: css, css-transforms

I worked with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfwD-AKRCcA), and coded this:

```js
Splitting();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: animate 8s linear infinite;
}

.circle .char {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--char-index) * 12deg)) translateZ(250px);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg) rotateX(15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(15deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle" data-splitting>
  Circle-Text-Animation-Effects-
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I realized that it doesn't work with Chrome and Firefox. They don't show the curvature. I tried to fix it with [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/), but it didn't help. Has anyone an idea how to solve this issue?

Here is how it should look like, and how it looks like with Safari:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra span around your letters that need to have `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

```js
Splitting();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: animate 8s linear infinite;
}
/* added this */
.circle > span {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
}
/**/
.circle .char {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: red;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--char-index) * 12deg)) translateZ(250px);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg) rotateX(15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(15deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle" data-splitting>
  Circle-Text-Animation-Effects-
</div>
```

Comment: Do you also have an idea how to always center the tape? I realized it's changing it's position a bit